# Bash: get location of stderr and stdout

Tags: bash, process, stdout, stderr

Say, hypothetically, I start a process in the background and redirect its `stdout` and `stderr` to an arbitrary file somewhere. Months later, the process is still running and I've forgotten where that file is. If I know the process's ID how can I programatically determine the location to where it's sending its output?

Comment: Look up the `lsof` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Linux, you can run:

```
ls -l /proc/PROCESS_ID/fd/1 /proc/PROCESS_ID/fd/2
```

Comment: You can use `readlink` instead of `ls -l`, to just get the filename.

Comment: @123: Thank you. Or with GNU find: `find /proc/PROCESS_ID/fd -name '[12]' -printf "%l\n"`

Comment: To those who want to run this command inside their script: You can run `ls -l /proc/$$/fd/*` to debug all file descriptors of the current shell. This works even inside `$()` (as [specified by posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02)).